# what is follow errors in opencv 247 and visual 2012?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

What is follow errors in opencv 247 and visual 2012?

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: ConsoleApplication8, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  Source.cpp
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseImage referenced in function _main
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvNamedWindow referenced in function _main
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvShowImage referenced in function _main
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvDestroyWindow referenced in function _main
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLoadImage referenced in function _main
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvWaitKey referenced in function _main
C:\Users\a\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\Debug\ConsoleApplication8.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: i am inserting for debug with d all library and without d for release

Answer (score 0):

you will have to link against opencv_core247d.lib and opencv_highgui247d.lib (without the d for release)